# Getting "unsupported GET request" from public_profile info

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'd like to know my Facebook ID but the "official" way of doing that

`http://graph.facebook.com/{user}` (obviously with my userid) gives an unsupported GET error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

Why is not working? The documentation says the the userid is always part of the public_profile. Are there any other ways of doing that?

Comment: how do you get that user id? is your user logged in? are you using an access token?

Comment: It's just my id, ugol70. Tried while logged in and out and it's the same. I compared the privacy preferences with other people and there are no visible differences.

Comment: You're sure you haven't disabled all platform apps from accessing your data in your privacy settings?

Comment: Yep, that was indeed the case. Using the Graph Api Explorer with the /me I spotted the thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ugol70" is not your id, it´s your username. You can´t use the username anymore. Only use the "App Scoped ID" you get after authorizing (either directly in the authorization process or with the `/me` endpoint).

..and ALWAYS use an Access Token for API calls. See the following links about Access Tokens, for example:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/